# Prism + Log4Net build error : "Cannot resolve dependency to assembly log4net"

Tags: reflection, log4net, prism

I am trying to add log4net support in a Prism application. Unfortunately i get the following error for each prism modules :

> Error 101 Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'  [PRISM MODULE 1 PROJECT NAME]
>
> Error 101 Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'  [PRISM MODULE 2 PROJECT NAME]
>
> ect ...

I set up the logger as follow :

1. I added log4net assembly reference to both the main app, and the bootstrapper.
2. I added log4net configuration to the app.config file.
3. I added [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] to the App.xaml.cs file.
4. I created a logger implemeting ILoggerFacade and overwrote CreateLogger() in the Bootstrapper to make it return my custom logger.

That's it.
If i try to build, it fails with the error mentioned above for each prism module project.
The only work around i found was to manually add log4net references to each prism modules projects which, i think, kind of defeats the abstraction between ILoggerFacade and the dependencies of the actual implementation.

The error suggest to use the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event, but i don't see how it could help here as it is a build error, not runtime.

Any suggestion ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem, each modules were referencing the bootstrapper which is just wrong, i removed that dependency and VOILA, fixed !